# Trying to understand what seems to be wrong from given stack trace in c#

Tags: c#, stack-trace

I am trying to understand what seems to be wrong from this stack trace. What is "Value" in this context and how does simple Any function throws an exception in this specific case.

Stack Trace:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
   at System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Object obj)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.ParseRawHeaderValues(String name, HeaderStoreItemInfo info, Boolean removeEmptyHeader)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.<GetEnumerator>d__20.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at PortalCoreV2.Controllers.HomeController.<FacebookShares>d__19.MoveNext() in **********\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 173
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
........
```

And here's line 173 of the HomeController:

```
private static HttpClient facebokPingHttpClient = new HttpClient()
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
        };

    [ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Default", Order = int.MaxValue)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FacebookShares(string articleIds)
    {
        if (facebokPingHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Any(m => m.Key == "user-agent") == false) <--- line 173
            facebokPingHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4");
```

Comment: I think you're manipulating `facebokPingHttpClient` at the same time from multiple threads. `HttpClient` is not thread-safe! Do not do this! If you need to set some headers, then create, configure, and assign `facebokPingHttpClient` from a static constructor, rather than from one of your instance methods

Comment: Could probably try to diagnose the current issue but I'd recommend just changing things around so that you create the HttpClient in a static constructor *and* assign the `DefaultRequestHeaders` there.

Comment: @canton7 - *some* aspects of `HttpClient` are specifically called out as thread-safe. However, the `DefaultXyz` properties aren't in that set.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but could the HttpClient be disposed?  Alternatively, you can set the default headers once (in initialization even) instead of doing it per method invocation.

Comment: I was thinking it could be a threading issue too, but kind of weird that the monitor object would be null.

Comment: Will try with static constructor. That's a good idea.

Comment: It locks on a parameter, [see here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs,752). I don't think it's possible for that parameter to be null in .NET Core, so I'm guessing this is Framework

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? GetEnumerator method of System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders invokes ParseRawHeaderValues passing values of HeaderStoreItemInfo items. One of them is null. Within the source code linked by @canton7, a GetEnumeratorCore method prevent using a null item, whereas the .Net 4.0 decompiled with ILSpy show that such check is missing!

Comment: @Rubidium37 Nice find -- I couldn't be bothered to decompile a Framework DLL to see what it did

Comment: @Rubidium It's ASP.NET core with .net framework 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my previous comments...

From further investigation by means of ILSpy, I was unable to find a method that can add a `null` `HeaderStoreItemInfo` object.
All candidate places seem to be properly guarded by null checks.

Meanwhile, it seem that the `HttpHeader`s class is NOT thread-safe, meaning that different threads simultaneously setting properties might corrupt the internal dictionary.
A similar effect might happen when reading while something else is writing.

I suggest adding synchronization locks around both code that is modifying and using the headers.

NOTE:
`FacebookShares` is both reading and writing headers; is it possible that two threads are running sych method simultaneously?

For example:

```
private static HttpClient facebokPingHttpClient = new HttpClient()
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
    };

private static readonly object HeadersLock = new object(); // DECLARED LOCK

[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Default", Order = int.MaxValue)]
public async Task<IActionResult> FacebookShares(string articleIds)
{
    lock(HeadersLock) // ADDED LOCK
    {
        if (!facebokPingHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Any(m => m.Key == "user-agent"))
            facebokPingHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4");
    }
}
```

You have to check your code to add the same exact lock everywhere `facebokPingHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders` could be modified.

Comment: It is quite possible. I've added problematic lines of code in static constructor, and the problem went away!